# How to select by attribute and loop through values to GetCount per month with ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I would like to write a script where I select a layer by the `[District]` attribute and loop through the field `[PickUpDate]` to get the count per district per month.  My month format is m/d/yyyy, i.e. `1/2/2015`.
Below I select the district in the Table View, I could easily use GetCount to get the total for my selection, but I need the count per month per District

Example:

```
alayer = 'PickUpColumns_12_1_2015_dups1'
hbclause = "[District] = 'HB'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(alayer,"NEW_SELECTION",hbclause)
```

Comment: I was literally about to ask this question, you saved me :). I will follow this thread. I am working on selecting by layer then using searchcursor, but as my arcGIS is 10.0 the da.searchcursor woun't work for me. what version is your arcgis?

Comment: I am using 10.2, you can use arcpy.searchcursor.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help./index.html#//000v00000039000000

Comment: Worth noting is that relational databases are designed to do this sort of grouping via SQL. arcpy would be toward the bottom of the list of technologies I would choose for this problem (only as sort of a last resort).

Comment: @ jpmc26 The best is work with distinct districts directly and existing start + end date in the table. I have create a script for that and you can modified as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all values in 2 uniques values list a. Next, create a product to get all possibilities and count. Test with this snippet

**Imports:**

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import arcpy
import itertools
import calendar
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

**functions for get unique list of values**

```
def boundary_date(table, field, where_clause=""):
    """ return first date and last date in table
        <tuple>(<datime.date>start_date, <datetime.date>end_date) """

    print "get boundary date"
    values = distinct_values(table, field)
    d1 = values[0]  # start value list
    d2 = values[-1] # end value list
    print d1, d2

    return (d1,d2)


def datetime_mmyyyy_couple_from_boundary(start,end):
    """ return list of date with a month delta based on start and end date
        <list>[(<datime.date>start_mm_date, <datetime.date>end_mm_date),...] """

    # add last day of month for end date
    start = start.replace(day=1)

    # add firt day of month for start date   
    end = end.replace(day=1) 

    # list od month
    count = (end.year - start.year)*12 + end.month - start.month 

    a = [start+relativedelta(months=i) for i in range(count+1)] # list of start month date
    b = [i.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(i.year, i.month)[1]) for i in a] # list of end mount date
    return zip(a,b) 


def distinct_values(table, field):
    """ Return distinct value content in field to list """
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor if row[0]})  # No blank data
```

**Main Process**

```
def main():
    """ Process to get count entities for distinct districts and month in
    PickUpDate"""
    path = 'E:/temp/sample.mdb/sampleTable'  # Need full path for AddFieldDelimiters
    tw = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(path, "sampleTable1")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(tw, "CLEAR_SELECTION")  # Clear selection if you use existing table and dont use makeTableView

    print "> Get count for all District and PickUpDate (month interval)"

    districts = distinct_values(tw,"District")
    bound_date = boundary_date(tw,"PickUpDate") # <tuple> ({start_date},{end_date})
    list_couple_dates = datetime_mmyyyy_couple_from_boundary(*bound_date)
    print list_couple_dates

    print "District,Start_Date,End_Date,Count"
    for a, b in itertools.product(districts, list_couple_dates):

        # Get data from time interval
        q_district = """{} = '{}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(path, "District"),a)
        q_date_1 = """{} >= #{}#""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(path, "PickUpDate"),b[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))  # Format date for MDB only!!!
        q_date_2 = """{} <= #{}#""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(path, "PickUpDate"),b[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))  # Format date for MDB only!!!
        # Get spécifique district
        query = """{} AND {} AND {}""".format(q_district,q_date_1,q_date_2)
        # print query  # Just for check Query
        fl_filter = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(tw, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
        count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fl_filter).getOutput(0))  

        print "{},{},{},{}".format(a,b[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),b[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),count)

        # clear filter
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fl_filter, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
    arcpy.Delete_management(fl_filter) #delete table view after work

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what should `fl` be defined as?

Comment: @GeoffreyWest this is your FeatureLayer or Your FeatureClass but i have just a question :  day in PickUpDate is same for one district or is can change? If it can change i need patch the snippet to return couple of start and end date

Comment: this value can change based on the day that the commodity was picked up.

Comment: @GeoffreyWest Ok i change my post in few minutes to change pick_up_date couple of values and change query in fl_filter

Comment: what should a, b be defined as?

Comment: @GeoffreyWest a, b is couple of distinct District and Date but date need to be change to start_date and end_date in this part of script for work with your data. Next a, b = 'HB',(date(2015,10,1),date(2015,10,31)) and in one line you have all you want to do for query count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32380/discussion-between-geostonemarten-and-geoffrey-west).

Answer (score 1):

this should be more efficient than running several selections and counting in a loop.

```
import arcpy
fc = 'PickUpColumns_12_1_2015_dups1'
fields =  ("District","PickUpDate") 
myDictionnary={}
count=12*[0]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row[0] in cursor:
            if row[0] in myDictionnary:
                myDictionnary[row[0]][int(row[1].split("/")[0])-1]+=1
            else:
                myDictionnary[row[0]]=count
                myDictionnary[row[0]][int(row[1].split("/")[0])-1]+=1
```

Count will contain the number of monthly pickups. Index starts at 0 so january is count[0] (therefore I use -1 for the index). row[0] will be the district name and row[1] the date string(I assumed that it is a string field and not a date field).

You can then query the number of months for any district

```
number_of_pickUp_for_month_and_district = myDictionnary[district_name][month-1]
```

rem : If you use SearchCursor instead of the da version, the row values will be *row.PickUpDate* and *row.Districts*

As a remark, if you concatenate district and month ( !District! + "_" + !PickUpDate!.split("/")[0] )  in a new field, you can use "summary statistics"

Comment: this script returns an error at line 5; `Runtime error SyntaxError: can't assign to function call (<string>, line 5)`

Comment: this is probably because I forgot to removre the [] when copy pasting the whereclause. I've edited my code.